# How to create a custom msg for arduino?

Tags: ros, arduino, ros-indigo, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to create the custom msg for Arduino. I refer the [rosserial_client](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_client/Tutorials/Generating%20Message%20Header%20Files) package to generate the custom msg.
I created the package `simbha_msg` for msgs. Package contains the msg file  `simbha_imu.msg`

```
    Header header
    float64 roll
    float64 pitch
    float64 yaw
```

I run the command `rosrun rosserial_client make_libraries /home/simmu/Desktop/ simbha_msgs/` but its not working as expected.
I tried with cpp node as well but that is also not working. It wont give any error or warnings.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291312/how-to-create-a-custom-msg-for-arduino-?/) by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2018-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ohk, I have solved the problem by myself. The problem was to make the changing in `CmakeLists.txt`.

I cleaned the build directory and rebuild it, that's solved my problem. :)

---

Originally posted by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) with karma: 241 on 2018-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapingo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35319/chapingo/) on 2018-05-22**:
Hi, I am facing  a similar problem. Could you mention which changes you made in `CmakeLists.txt`

**Comment by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) on 2018-05-22**:
refer this [link](http://wiki.ros.org/action/show/msg?action=show&redirect=ROS%2FMessage_Description_Language)